# How to use only one instance of Array in this code?

Tags: java

this question is going to be silly. But can someone please explain to me why I cannot use the same array int[] a1 for 2 methods?

Let's say I have an **ArrayObject** class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ArrayObject implements ArrayFunctions {

    private int[] arr;

    public ArrayObject(int[] arr) {
        super();
        this.arr = arr;
    } 


    @Override
    public int[] sortAsc() {
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        return arr;
    }


    @Override
    public int[] sortDesc() {
        int temp;
        int size = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++)
          {
             temp = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[size-1 - i];
             arr[size-1 - i] = temp;
          }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Then in **Main** class

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] a1 = {2,9,45,7,46,35,89,12,456,12,5,35,4,98,34};

        ArrayObject arr1 = new ArrayObject(a1);
        ArrayObject arr2 = new ArrayObject(a1);

        int[] sortedArray = arr1.sortAsc();
        int[] sortDescArray = arr2.sortDesc();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortDescArray));

    }

}
```

The result is:

[456, 98, 89, 46, 45, 35, 35, 34, 12, 12, 9, 7, 5, 4, 2]

[456, 98, 89, 46, 45, 35, 35, 34, 12, 12, 9, 7, 5, 4, 2]

How can I re-use the array int[] a1 for both array sorting method, without making new arrays with same elements?

Base on my code,

```
ArrayObject arr2 = new ArrayObject(a1);
```

will another instance of ArrayObject create a brand-new array with the same element with **arr1**?

Please help!

Comment: Short answer - you can't.  Not if you're expecting both instance of `ArrayObject` to get unsorted data.  The problem is, `ArrayObject` is modifying the SAME reference of the array. You will need to use something like `System.arraycopy()` to ensure that each instance of `ArrayObject` is acting on an independent copy of the original array

Comment: The value of a Java `int[]` is a reference type. You are assigning the same reference to the `int[]` in arr1 and arr2. Although in your post you named them both arr1.

Comment: you are not creating any brand new array other than `arr[]`, you are always using same array for two sort methods, if you like to check array is same or not check `hashCode()` in two sort methods

Comment: @ElliottFrisch my mistake, it should be arr2. But the result still the same.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Much appreciated. I got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is analogy time:

If Jack has a 1 gallon bucket, he can fill it with one gallon of beer, or he can fill it with one gallon of cider.  But Jack cannot fill his one gallon bucket with one gallon of beer and one gallon of cider *at the same time*.

Likewise, Jack can stir the bucket contents with a stick, so that it rotates in a clockwise or anti-clockwise direction.  But Jack can't make the beer / cider / water / whatever rotate in both directions at the same time.

When Jack and Jill come back from the [off-license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_licence) holding their bucket<sup>1</sup> it is still just one bucket holding at most one gallon ... despite the fact that both Jack and Jill are both holding the handle at the same time.

---

An array is like a bucket.   If you have one array shared by two `ArrayObject` instances, it is still just one array.  It can be sorted in ascending order or in descending order ... but not both at the same time<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1 - ... of beer: they are undergraduates in this version of the story.</sup>

<sup>2 - ... unless all the array element values are the same.</sup>