# String Array Syntax

Tags: java, arrays

Take this snippet of code for example:

```
String[] s = new String[2];
s[0] = "Alex";
s[1] = "John";
String[] t = {"Michael", "Megan", "Chelsea"};
s = t;
System.out.println(s.length);
```

When run, why would this print out 3 instead of giving out a compile or run time error?

Comment: The length of the array is not part of the data type.

Comment: Instead of arrays let talk about buckets. `s` is a bucket. `t` is a second bucket. After `s = t;` you throw away the first bucket, and put the handle named `s` on the bucket named `t`. Thus when you say how big is my bucket with `System.out.println(s.length);` you only have **one** bucket. The one that holds three names.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That makes sense now. Essentially what's happening here is that I'm redirecting s to what t is pointing to as well right?

Comment: Yes. After `s = t` it is true that `s == t`.

Comment: Or maybe to phrase it in other words, you've *reassigned* a value to `s`, *instead of updating* it.

Comment: Hey Elliott ... that's *my* story :-)   https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147802/139985

Comment: @StephenC Much like with Apple and Microsoft, I can only point at [Xerox](https://ihasabucket.com/). And of course [Joseph Campbell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hero_with_a_Thousand_Faces).

Answer (score 0):

Why there should be a compile time or run time error?

With **s = t** you are making **s** point to same array to which **t** is pointing, in other words they both are referring to **same memory location** where array is stored.